# Create dynamic columns in SQL Server table connected to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am new new ASP.NET MVC and databases. I want to create a table in SQL Server with some columns, but the number of columns depends on the data coming from a datafile on ASP.NET, any suggestions? Thanks for your answers in advance!

It's an ASP.NET MVC app, so I am trying to create dynamic model but it's not yet working...

Comment: You need to show us (code) what you have tried, then we can help you resolve this issue in a way they you are likely to understand. Read more about [mre]

Comment: Probably you might need No SQL DBs or Document DBs or at least check how to store JSON or XML documents in SQL server DB.